# Mapview zoom in IOS6

Tags: ios6, mkmapview, zooming, iphone-5

I am doing a mapview application. I have a set of contacts with addresses, which I convert into co ordinates using

```
-(CLLocationCoordinate2D) getLocationFromAddressString:(NSString*) addressStr {

NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%@&output=csv",
                    [addressStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSString *locationStr = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr] encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:nil];
NSArray *items = [locationStr componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
double latitude = 0.0;
double longitude = 0.0;


if([items count] >= 4 && [[items objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"200"]) {
    latitude = [[items objectAtIndex:2] doubleValue];
    longitude = [[items objectAtIndex:3] doubleValue];
}
CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
location.latitude = latitude;
location.longitude = longitude;

return location;
}
```

The mapview should be loaded in an optimum zoomed format, where all pins on the map should be visible to the user at once and the user should be able to zoom in and zoom out. I have found a way to solve this issue in previous IOS versions.
 I am facing problems in IOS6. Need help.

Edit: This is the code I have used to zoom

```
for(MKPointAnnotation* annotation in annotationArray)
{
    topLeftCoord.longitude = fmin(topLeftCoord.longitude, annotation.coordinate.longitude);
    topLeftCoord.latitude = fmax(topLeftCoord.latitude, annotation.coordinate.latitude);

    bottomRightCoord.longitude = fmax(bottomRightCoord.longitude, annotation.coordinate.longitude);
    bottomRightCoord.latitude = fmin(bottomRightCoord.latitude, annotation.coordinate.latitude);
}

MKCoordinateRegion region;
region.center.latitude = topLeftCoord.latitude - (topLeftCoord.latitude - bottomRightCoord.latitude) * 0.5;
region.center.longitude = topLeftCoord.longitude + (bottomRightCoord.longitude - topLeftCoord.longitude) * 0.5;
region.span.latitudeDelta = fabs(topLeftCoord.latitude - bottomRightCoord.latitude) * 1.1;
region.span.longitudeDelta = fabs(bottomRightCoord.longitude - topLeftCoord.longitude) * 1.1;

region = [mapViews regionThatFits:region];
[mapView setRegion:region animated:NO];
```

The problem I am facing is that, there is some inconsistency in the way, the map zooms to the region, where its meant to zoom.

Edit: The problem is that, if I have a contact with address in England and another contact with address in Japan, the mapview is not able to display both the pins at the same time. It will zoom into an area which would be the exact centre of the whole area including England and Japan, which means, neither pin will be displayed on the mapview. I need to slide to either sides to view the 2 pins. This has something to do with the maximum zoom level of the mapview.

Comment: Can you explain why your previous solution doesn't work? Where does it fail? The solutions I have seen for this problem don't involve any code that fails with iOS 6.

Comment: What you've got there should work fine* in iOS 6, I'd be looking else where for the inconsistencies. to be 100% sure it is this code, put the same data in for both iOS 5 and 6 and check the coordinates' values after the loop and the region calculation.

      *Personally I'd refactor the region lines like `region.center.latitude = topLeftCoord.latitude - (topLeftCoord.latitude - bottomRightCoord.latitude) * 0.5;` to `region.center.latitude = (topLeftCoord.latitude + bottomRightCoord.latitude) * 0.5;`

Comment: I have edited my question again

Comment: Ah, totally misunderstood. Yes iOS 6 seems to have a different minimum zoom level. There doesn't seem to be anything you can do to change that one.